# sql update query not running

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to test the following mySql query within phpmyadmin before using it within a test enviorment page.

my result should update the donate_Total by adding a value of 2000 to the exsisting value held and storing the total in there where the first_Name and last_Name are matched. I have the user named in the sql code below but this won't run, any pointers?

```
UPDATE `donate` SET `donate_Total`=  'donate_Total' + 2000 WHERE first_Name = 'Test'     AND last_Name ='One' ;
```

table name is donate and column name to update is donate_Total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change 'donate_total' to  donate_total without the quotes. You are trying to add two intergers together, therefore you cannot put it as a string.

```
 UPDATE `donate` SET `donate_Total`=  donate_Total + 2000 WHERE first_Name = 'Test'     AND last_Name ='One' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to add `2000` to your `donate_total`. If `2000` is not the name of a column then leave the `[]` and the `'`

```
UPDATE `donate` 
SET donate_Total =  donate_Total + 2000
WHERE first_Name = 'Test'     
AND last_Name ='One' ;
```